# Dependent Selects in Symfony2

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony

I'm trying to make two dependent selects, but can not get ajax call to make it work.
my ajax call is:

```
 var data = {
    tower_id:$(this).val();
 };

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "{{ path('select_apartment')}}",
    data:data,
    success: function(data) {
        var $apartment_selector = $('#apartamentos_apartamentosbundle_resident_apartmentid');

        $apartment_selector.html('<option>Apartamentos</option>');

        for (var i=0, total = data.length; i < total; i++) {
            $apartment_selector.append('<option value="' + data[i].id + '">' + data[i].number + '</option>');
        }
    }       
});
```

the method in the controller is:

```
  public function ApartmentsAction(Request $request){
$tower_id = $request->request->get('tower_id');
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$apartments = $em->getRepository('ApartamentosApartamentosBundle:Apartment')->findByTowerId($tower_id);


return new JsonResponse($apartments);}
```

It is as if the javascript does not call the method. the route of the method is :

```
 *@Route("/residentapt", name="select_apartment")
```

what i am doing wrong? any ideas?

thank you .

Comment: `$apartment_selector` shouldn't have the `$` symbol. It's Javascript, not PHP.

Comment: 're right, I corrected but I still have the problem .. not the method of the controller is running. it is okay make the call in post? This java script is running in the onchange of the first select.

Comment: Check first if your Javascript function is executed with any `console.log`. Yes, it is right to use POST.

Comment: i check te console and it works but in the select show the quantity of elements but say : undefined .